# Read user home directory from PHP

Tags: php, environment-variables, home-directory

I cannot find a way to get the user's home directory (e.g. */home/jack*; whatever ~ in bash points to) in PHP using CGI (suPHP). The $_ENV array is empty, and getenv('HOME') returns nothing.

The reason I want to do this is that in absense of configuration saying otherwise, I want to find variable files used by my application in */home/user/.myappnamehere*, as most Linux applications do.

---

I've built something, but it's not the best; While it works, it assumes a lot about the system (e.g. the presence of /etc/passwd)

```
 $usr = get_current_user();
    $passwd = file('/etc/passwd');
    $var = false;
    foreach ($passwd as $line) {
        if (strstr($line, $usr) !== false) {
            $parts = explode(':', $line);
            $var = realpath($parts[5].'/.report');
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: PHP using CGI? Who would be the current user in that context?

Comment: Because of suPHP (and also with suexec and whatever other ways there are) the PHP process is run as the user who owns the script (.php) file.

Comment: Your solution also assumes, that the user the script runs as is allowed to read the file, which normaly only root should be able to do...

Comment: On my Ubuntu 9.04 server which has no special configuration in that area, /etc/passwd's mode is -rwxr--r--, so readable for everybody. This is normal, because many application require access to it for e.g. authentication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want the result of either:
http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.getmyuid.php or
http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-getuid.php sent to
http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-getpwuid.php

Comment: Perfect. Do you happen to know a Windows equivalent?

Comment: After looking through the manual a bit, you may be able to use the W32api ( http://us.php.net/manual/en/w32api.examples-uptime.php ) along with SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_PERSONAL?) ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181%28VS.85%29.aspx ) to get the My Documents folder on Windows

Answer (score 4):

If `safemode` is disabled, try this one

```
$homedir = `cd ~ && pwd`;
```